# Copy/Cut/Paste in TMUX

Tags: ubuntu, tmux

I know this has been asked, but I am honestly unable to get any of the examples to work. Maybe because I am misunderstanding some technical shorthand.

I am looking for the basest of cases. I am running in Ubuntu 18.04 and the latest tmux.

When I use the mouse to select some text in tmux (e.g. an error message because I want to google it) the selection is yellow until I release the mouse and then the yellow disappears. I am actually curious why it works that way to begin with, but that's not important.

I would like to select the text in the tmux shell and then change windows, e.g. to Chrome or VSCode and "paste" it there. I don't have a three button mouse in case that matters. And I don't care too much yet about cut/paste between tmux sessions or tmux panes. Just simple cut/paste or copy/paste from my tmux shell to another window.

[Don't get mad, I have tried multiple of the .tmux.conf sequences and I don't understand how to get them to work.]

#### An answer

It seems something as simple as 
*holding down SHIFT while using the mouse to select*  allows me to also use a "rightclick" to locate an old-fashioned copy/paste menu. I believe this is the answer but I am leaving this up to see if anyone will shed more light.

Comment: Yes, shift will disable tmux mouse and allow you to copy/paste using your terminal emulator. It is same in vim if the mouse enabled. You can disable mouse in your tmux config using ```set -g mouse off ``` but you will not be able to use mouse to click and activate panes. There is an other way to copy in tmux using keyboard, which is mode-vi. You can have look at my tmux config file https://gitlab.com/NimaSaed/dotfiles/raw/master/.tmux.conf?inline=false